# Multicell in fpdf in php

Tags: php, fpdf

This is my 1st Page whose name is ex.php, when run on ex.php then output pdf comes and pdf table is overwrite each other. how to solve that problem, please help me,advanced thanks

```
<?php
require('mysql_table.php');

class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{
function Header()
{
    //Title
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
    $this->Cell(0,6,'World populations',0,1,'C');
    $this->Ln(10);
    //Ensure table header is output
    parent::Header();
}
}

//Connect to database
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('pro');

$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
//First table: put all columns automatically
$pdf->Table('select * from products');
$pdf->AddPage();
//Second table: specify 3 columns
$pdf->AddCol('Name',20,'','C');
$pdf->AddCol('Price',40,'','C');
//$pdf->AddCol('pop',40,'Pop (2001)','R');
$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150),
            'color1'=>array(210,245),
            'color2'=>array(255,255),
            'padding'=>2);
$pdf->Table('select Name, Price from products');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

This is another page whose name is mysql_table.php

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF_MySQL_Table extends FPDF
{
var $ProcessingTable=false;
var $aCols=array();
var $TableX;
var $HeaderColor;
var $RowColors;
var $ColorIndex;

function Header()
{
    //Print the table header if necessary
    if($this->ProcessingTable)
        $this->TableHeader();
}

function TableHeader()
{
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $this->SetX($this->TableX);
    $fill=!empty($this->HeaderColor);
    if($fill)
        $this->SetFillColor($this->HeaderColor[0],$this->HeaderColor[1],$this->HeaderColor[2]);
    foreach($this->aCols as $col)
        $this->Cell($col['w'],6,$col['c'],1,0,'C',$fill);
    $this->Ln();
}

function Row($data)
{
    $this->SetX($this->TableX);
    $ci=$this->ColorIndex;
    $fill=!empty($this->RowColors[$ci]);
    if($fill)
        $this->SetFillColor($this->RowColors[$ci][0],$this->RowColors[$ci][1],$this->RowColors[$ci][2]);
    foreach($this->aCols as $col)
        $this->Cell($col['w'],5,$data[$col['f']],1,0,$col['a'],$fill);
    $this->Ln();
    $this->ColorIndex=1-$ci;
}

function CalcWidths($width,$align)
{
    //Compute the widths of the columns
    $TableWidth=0;
    foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
    {
        $w=$col['w'];
        if($w==-1)
            $w=$width/count($this->aCols);
        elseif(substr($w,-1)=='%')
            $w=$w/100*$width;
        $this->aCols[$i]['w']=$w;
        $TableWidth+=$w;
    }
    //Compute the abscissa of the table
    if($align=='C')
        $this->TableX=max(($this->w-$TableWidth)/2,0);
    elseif($align=='R')
        $this->TableX=max($this->w-$this->rMargin-$TableWidth,0);
    else
        $this->TableX=$this->lMargin;
}

function AddCol($field=-1,$width=-1,$caption='',$align='L')
{
    //Add a column to the table
    if($field==-1)
        $field=count($this->aCols);
    $this->aCols[]=array('f'=>$field,'c'=>$caption,'w'=>$width,'a'=>$align);
}

function Table($query,$prop=array())
{
    //Issue query
    $res=mysql_query($query) or die('Error: '.mysql_error()."<BR>Query: $query");
    //Add all columns if none was specified
    if(count($this->aCols)==0)
    {
        $nb=mysql_num_fields($res);
        for($i=0;$i<$nb;$i++)
            $this->AddCol();
    }
    //Retrieve column names when not specified
    foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
    {
        if($col['c']=='')
        {
            if(is_string($col['f']))
                $this->aCols[$i]['c']=ucfirst($col['f']);
            else
                $this->aCols[$i]['c']=ucfirst(mysql_field_name($res,$col['f']));
        }
    }
    //Handle properties
    if(!isset($prop['width']))
        $prop['width']=0;
    if($prop['width']==0)
        $prop['width']=$this->w-$this->lMargin-$this->rMargin;
    if(!isset($prop['align']))
        $prop['align']='C';
    if(!isset($prop['padding']))
        $prop['padding']=$this->cMargin;
    $cMargin=$this->cMargin;
    $this->cMargin=$prop['padding'];
    if(!isset($prop['HeaderColor']))
        $prop['HeaderColor']=array();
    $this->HeaderColor=$prop['HeaderColor'];
    if(!isset($prop['color1']))
        $prop['color1']=array();
    if(!isset($prop['color2']))
        $prop['color2']=array();
    $this->RowColors=array($prop['color1'],$prop['color2']);
    //Compute column widths
    $this->CalcWidths($prop['width'],$prop['align']);
    //Print header
    $this->TableHeader();
    //Print rows
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',11);
    $this->ColorIndex=0;
    $this->ProcessingTable=true;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        $this->Row($row);
    $this->ProcessingTable=false;
    $this->cMargin=$cMargin;
    $this->aCols=array();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: i stop this, but still comes in disorder manner